# Google Tag Manager JavaScript Compiler Error

Tags: google-tag-manager

The Error

Validate Container
The container has the following errors:
Type    Location    Description
JavaScript compiler error
Keyvendors_whastaap

> Error at line 6, character 27: This language feature is only supported
> for ECMASCRIPT_2015 mode or better: arrow function.

The Code

```
<!-- Chat Plugin Code New  -->

<script async src='https://d2mpatx37cqexb.cloudfront.net/delightchat-whatsapp-widget/embeds/embed.min.js'></script>
<script>
var wa_btnSetting = {"btnColor":"#2CCD47","ctaText":"Book on Whatsapp","cornerRadius":40,"marginBottom":20,"marginLeft":20,"marginRight":20,"btnPosition":"left","whatsAppNumber":"917678462928","welcomeMessage":"I need to book home service.","zIndex":999999,"btnColorScheme":"light"};
window.onload = () => {
  _waEmbed(wa_btnSetting);
};
</script>
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-7890504903052561"
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
      
<!-- Your Chat Plugin code -->
```

whats the error how I fix it ?

trying to add whatsaao widget throough GTM in all pages except one page. but the tag have an error.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that you use an arrow function in your code. You can't do that in GTM.

Rewrite this:

```
window.onload = () => {
  _waEmbed(wa_btnSetting);
};
```

into this:

```
window.onload = function(){
  _waEmbed(wa_btnSetting);
};
```